# Encoding issue with gson.stream.JsonReader - works correctly in java app but not in jar, even when using StandardCharsets.UTF_8

Tags: java, encoding, jar, gson

When reading a json file in the following format, with specific `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` settings:

```
  JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(theFile), 
                              StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                jsonReader.beginArray();
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                    JSONObject currentJsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JSONObject.class);
                    // work on json object
                }
```

When the code is running within the intellij it reads with no  problems signs such as ⚛ ♛.

Once I package the code into a jar and run it, on Windows machine, on the same input, it reads these sings as `?` signs.

When omitting the UTF-8 encoding and changing the line to be

`JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(currentFile)));`

Then again the application within the intellij reads the signs correctly, but the jar reads them as `â??`

Is there a need to package the jar differently? Or run the jar with another parameter in order for it to read the signs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem seems to be originated in the command-line tool that I used to run the program.

When the jar was run in a Linux machine it read all these signs correctly.

Back in my personal windows machine, I opened a Git-bash command line terminal and run the jar and it run ok.